wkhtmltopdf not loading css
I am making a PDF generator and right now I'm using pdfkit on python (which uses wkhtmltopdf). The pdf generates fine but the stylesheet isn't applied to the pdf. I know this because there is no spacing and also because images are being split between pages.
I am running this inside a docker container with a dockerfile and I use RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf to install it
The code that I use for generating the pdf is:
options = {
            'page-size': "A4",
            'margin-top': '0.65in',
            'margin-right': '0.65in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.65in',
            'margin-left': '0.65in',
            'zoom': 0.8,
            'user-style-sheet': '/app/lib/templates/topical.css'
        }

qp_pdf = pdfkit.from_string(q_html, f'_tmp/tmp_qs_{record.data[0]["id"]}.pdf', options=options)

I have tried:

using the 'user-style-sheet' option (tried both the absolute path and path from work directory)
using pdfkit's css option (tried both the absolute path and path from work directory)
adding a style tag to the html
using a link tag (gives me error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to /tmp/runtime-root which stops the pdf generation)

Generally confused about wkhtmltopdf. Also, whenever I set an option such as --disable-smart-shrinking or --header-center, it says it's not supported on "unpatched qt" which I have no idea about.
I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 and pdfkit==1.0.0
